# QGIS Plugin development : Error when running the plugin code in the QGIS Python code editor

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

When running my main dowload_boku.py code in the Python QGIS code editor I get an error. While the plugin itself is working in QGIS. Anybody an idea?

The error occurs without any adjustments to the code. My goal is to extend the functionality of the plugin later.

How can I solve this?

This is the error I get :

````
exec(Path('C:/Users/dmpet/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/COALAQGISplugin-main/download_boku.py').read_text())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```


This are the log messages I get :



2024-01-27T16:02:57     WARNING    warning:C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py:888: ImportWarning: can't resolve package from __spec__ or __package__, falling back on __name__ and __path__
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
             
             traceback: File "C:\Users/dmpet/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\COALAQGISplugin-main\download_boku.py", line 414, in run
              result = self.dlg.exec_()
              File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console.py", line 658, in runScriptEditor
              self.tabEditorWidget.currentWidget().newEditor.runScriptCode()
              File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_editor.py", line 453, in runScriptCode
              self.parent.pc.shell.runCommand("exec(Path('{0}').read_text())"
              File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 520, in runCommand
              more = self.runsource(src)
              File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\console\console_sci.py", line 553, in runsource
              return super(ShellScintilla, self).runsource(source, filename, symbol)
              File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 74, in runsource
              self.runcode(code)
              File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
              exec(code, self.locals)
              File "", line 1, in 
              File "", line 36, in 
              File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis-ltr/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 888, in _import
              mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)             
```
````

Comment: Please paste the error code as text rather a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @Padmanabha i added the error code.